# cell acessory view dissappears when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an expandable list, and when I scroll some accessory views disappear and I don't understand why.
The expandable rows have an accessory view (+ or -). The rest of rows haven't accessory view.

I tried `[table reloadTable]` but nothing, and I tried some things about resuable cells but nothing too.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section]) // Todas las filas se pueden expandir
    {

        NSMutableArray *aux = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        InfoTitulacion_DTO *rowData = [self.asignaturas objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        [aux addObject: rowData];
        [aux addObjectsFromArray: rowData.asignaturas];

        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            if ([rowData.nombre isEqualToString:@"optativos"]) {
                cell.textLabel.text = AMLocalizedString(@"optativos", @"");
            }else{

                cell.textLabel.text = [AMLocalizedString(rowData.nombre, @"") stringByAppendingString:AMLocalizedString(@"cursoLabel", @"")];
            }
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"";

            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
            }else{
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
            }
            cell.indentationLevel = 0;


            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
            {

                UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Minus-256.png"];
                [abrirButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.accessoryView = abrirButton;

            }
            else
            {
                abrirButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
                cell.accessoryView = abrirButton;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            // all other rows
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            }else{
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
            }

            AsignaturaTitulacion_DTO *asig_dto = [[AsignaturaTitulacion_DTO alloc] initWithAsignaturaTitulacion:[aux objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            cell.textLabel.text = asig_dto.nombre;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[[AMLocalizedString(@"creditosAsig", @"") stringByAppendingString:asig_dto.creditos] stringByAppendingString:@"   "] stringByAppendingString:AMLocalizedString(@"caracter", @"")] stringByAppendingString:asig_dto.caracter];
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.indentationLevel = 1;
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And the other function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:table canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            [self.table beginUpdates];

            UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [table deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:table numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];
                UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Minus-256.png"];
                [abrirButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.accessoryView = abrirButton;
            }
            else
            {
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:table numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                abrirButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
                cell.accessoryView = abrirButton;
            }


            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }



            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                [table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                abrirButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
                cell.accessoryView = abrirButton;

            }
            else
            {
                [table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
//                abrirButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
                UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Minus-256.png"];
                [abrirButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.accessoryView = abrirButton;

            }

            [self.table endUpdates];

        }
    }
}
```

Images:

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: Can you please explain extremely explicitly what exactly is supposed to happen?

Comment: The + or - images disappear when I scroll the table.

Comment: It seems that the cell is reused and the accessory view fails..

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset you cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath because tableview reuses cell. And you might be hidding accessory view for some cell and its being reused as it is.

It would be something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

[self configureCell:cell];
//continue your logic
```

....
...

```
}

- (void) configureCell:(UITableViewCell*) cell{
{
      //Rest all the values of your cell to default. 
}
```